# What is a mathematic rigorous definition of "blue noise"?

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, noise, white-noise

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $I$ be a finite nonempty set, $(x_i)_{i\in I}\subseteq[0,1)^d$, $(w_i)_{i\in I}\subseteq[0,\infty)$ with $\sum_{i\in I}w_i=1$ and $$\sigma:=\sum_{i\in I}w_i\delta_{x_i}.$$

I really got trouble to understand what's meant by the property of the point pattern $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ to "admit blue noise characteristic". I think the term "blue noise" is used quite vaguely in the literature. One think I've often read is that $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ has "blue noise charateristic" if the corresponding power spectrum is near $0$ for low frequencies. This should mean that the absolute value of the Fourier transform $$\hat\sigma(x)=\sum_{i\in I}w_ie^{-{\rm i}2\pi\langle x,\:x_i\rangle}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R^d$$ is small (or near $0$) whenever $\left\|x\right\|$ is small.

There are also papers (like [Blue Noise through Optimal Transport](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Ekbreeden/pub/dGBOD12.pdf) and [Blue Moise Wasserstein Sampling](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Wasserstein-blue-noise-sampling-Qin-Chen/6927537f2cad12a337d88a4922e91b4a591adb71)) which seem to relate the blue noise property to a suitable minimization of a Wasserstein distance, but I actually don't understand why and in which sense that minimizer has blue noise characteristics.

What I actually would like to investigate is whether a specific Markov chain (e.g. generated by the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm) has blue noise characteristics.

Comment: In the electrical acoustics world (at the intersection of psychoacoustics and signal processing), blue noise is characterized in a pretty standard fashion as a 3dB/octave slope on the graph of intensity (sound pressure) versus frequency (formally, power density's rate of increase is $\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(10)} = 3.01dB$ per octave). However, this spectrum definition can also apply to frequency ranges outside of human hearing, and, indeed to electromagnetic wave frequencies rather than sound waves, or to mathematically abstract frequencies.

Comment: @Alexis Thank you for your comment. I'm interested in the definition used in computer graphics, which is motivated by the human visual system: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/16330738_Spectral_Consequences_of_Photoreceptor_Sampling_in_the_Rhesus_Retina.

Comment: For any given frequency range—including those in he visual spectrum—blue noise is *blue* because more energy is massed at higher frequencies, i.e. blue shifted compared to white noise over the same range..

Comment: @Alexis So, doesn't that precisely mean that $\hat\sigma(x)$ is near $0$ whenever $\left\|x\right\|$ is small?